# How to get price source from an Historical API request

Tags: bloomberg

In my production C# application, I make several Historical request (using "//blp/refdata" service) to get security prices.
For bonds, I would like to know which is the Price Source used by Bloomberg to give me the results.

I tried to make a request using the FEED_SOURCE and PRICING_SOURCE fields, but doesn't work (these fields are not historical).

Does anybody solved a similar problem?

Below a piece of code:

```cs
Service refDataService = d_session.GetService("//blp/refdata");
// create historical request
Request request = RefDataService.CreateRequest("HistoricalDataRequest");
    
// set securities to request
Element securities = request.GetElement("securities");
foreach (string sec in ticker)
{
  securities.AppendValue(sec);
}
 // set fields to request
 Element fields = request.GetElement("fields");
    
 fields.AppendValue("px_last");
 fields.AppendValue("PRICING_SOURCE");
 fields.AppendValue("FEED_SOURCE");
    
 // send request
 d_session.SendRequest(request, null);
```

In the Bloomberg answer, I receive the following:

```cs
{securityData = {    security = "XXX Corp"    eidData[] = {    }    sequenceNumber = 0    fieldExceptions[] = {        fieldExceptions = {            fieldId = "PRICING_SOURCE"            errorInfo = {                source = "163::bbdbh1"                code = 1                category = "BAD_FLD"                message = "Not valid historical field"                subcategory = "NOT_APPLICABLE_TO_HIST_DATA"            }        }    }    fieldData[] = {        fieldData = {            date = 2021-11-15            px_last = 100.785            px_bid = 100.729            px_open = 101.153            px_high = 101.558            px_low = 100.785            px_ask = 100.841        }        fieldData = {            date = 2021-11-16            px_last = 100.045            px_bid = 99.865            px_open = 100.795            px_high = 100.795            px_low = 100.045            px_ask = 100.226        }    }}}
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of the code you are using, and any errors you get? Otherwise your question is a little vague.

Comment: Depending on the ticker, it may be easier to put the source directly in the ticker "XXX@SOURCE Corp".

Comment: @assylias Do you need the @? I’ve always used tickers like `EUSA2 ICPL Curncy`, to get ICAP pricing.